# Error DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

Tengo el siguiente problema a ver si me pueden ayudar. Estoy usando un dataTable para mostrar las OP de mi sistema. Tengo que agregar dos columnas dependiendo del usuario, si es un usuario administrador debo mostrar dos columnas adicionales, sino dependiendo del usuario se mostrara uno de esas columnas:

```js
var dtTable = $('#tabla1').DataTable({
  "ajax": {
    "url": 'orden_pedido_acciones.php?accion=' + accionv,
    "dataSrc": ""
  },
  "columns": [{
      "data": null,
      "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
        return meta.row + 1; // La columna 0 ahora contendrá el número consecutivo
      }
    },
    {"data": "ORDEN_PEDIDO_NUMERO"},
    {"data": "CLIENTE_NOMBRE"},
    {"data": "CIUDAD_NOMBRE"},
    {"data": "BODEGA_NOMBRE"},
    {"data": "ORDEN_PEDIDO_FECHA_CREACION"},
    {
      "data": "REFERENCIA",
      "render": function(data, type, row) {
        // Reemplaza las comas con saltos de línea
        return data.replace(/,/g, '<br>');
      }
    },
    {
      "data": "CANT",
      "render": function(data, type, row) {
        // Reemplaza las comas con saltos de línea
        return data.replace(/,/g, '<br>');
      }
    },
    {
      "data": "CATEGORIA_NOMBRE",
      "render": function(data, type, row) {
        // Reemplaza las comas con saltos de línea
        return data.replace(/,/g, '<br>');
      }
    },
    {"data": "NOMBRE"},
    {"data": "ORDEN_PEDIDO_ESTADO"},
    {
      "data": null,
      "orderable": false,
      "className": 'dt-body-center',
      "render": function(data, type, row) {
        // Contenido de la columna "Bloquear"
        if (tipoUser == 1 || tipoUser == 2 || grupo == 11) {
          return '<a href="?bloqueo=' + row.ORDEN_PEDIDO_ID + '" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;" class="bloquear hint--bottom-left hint--rounded hint--info" aria-label="Bloquear OP No. ' + row.ORDEN_PEDIDO_NUMERO + '"><span class="icon-eye1" style="font-size: 22px !important;"></span></a>';
        } else
          return '';
      }
    },
    /*{
        "data": null,
        "orderable": false,
        "className": 'dt-body-center',
        "render": function (data, type, row) {
            // Contenido de la columna "Confirmar"
            console.log("Row data:", row);
            if (row && row.ORDEN_PEDIDO_ID && (tipoUser == 1 || tipoUser == 2 || grupo == 15)) {
                return '<a href="?pago=' + row.ORDEN_PEDIDO_ID + '" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;" class="confirmar hint--bottom-left hint--rounded hint--info" aria-label="Confirmar Pago"><span class="icon-check1"></span></a>';
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }
    },*/
    {"data": "ORDEN_PEDIDO_DOC_HELISA"},
    {"data": "ORDEN_PEDIDO_DOC_ISUPPORT"},
    {"data": null,"orderable": false}
  ],
  columnDefs: [{
      targets: -1,
      className: 'dt-body-center',
      "defaultContent": "<button class='btn btn-outline-secondary botonEditar'><span class='icon-edit1'></span></button>",
      data: null
    },
  ],
  'rowCallback': function(row, data, index) {
    var button = $(row).find('td:eq(7) button'); //Se captura el boton de editar
    button.attr('value', data.ORDEN_PEDIDO_ID); //Se asigna el ID de la campaña
  },
  "lengthMenu": [
    [10, 25, 50, -1],
    [10, 25, 50, "Todos"]
  ]
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-stripped table-bordered table-hover" id="tabla1" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">No. OP</th>
      <th scope="col">Cliente</th>
      <th scope="col">Ciudad</th>
      <th scope="col">Bodega</th>
      <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
      <th scope="col">Referencia</th>
      <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
      <th scope="col">Categoría</th>
      <th scope="col">Vendedor</th>
      <th scope="col">Estado</th>
      <?php 
                if ($tipoUser == 1 || $tipoUser == 2 || $grupo == 11){
                    echo '<th scope="col">Bloquear</th>';
                }else if ($tipoUser == 1 || $tipoUser == 2 || $grupo == 15){
                    echo '<th scope="col">Confirmar</th>';
                }   
            ?>
      <th scope="col">No. Factura</th>
      <th scope="col">No. Salida</th>
      <th scope="col">PDF</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Pero cuando agrego el contenido:

```
{
                        "data": null,
                        "orderable": false,
                        "className": 'dt-body-center',
                        "render": function (data, type, row) {
                            // Contenido de la columna "Confirmar"
                            console.log("Row data:", row);
                            if (row && row.ORDEN_PEDIDO_ID && (tipoUser == 1 || tipoUser == 2 || grupo == 15)) {
                                return '<a href="?pago=' + row.ORDEN_PEDIDO_ID + '" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;" class="confirmar hint--bottom-left hint--rounded hint--info" aria-label="Confirmar Pago"><span class="icon-check1"></span></a>';
                            } else {
                                return '';
                            }
                        }
                    },
```

Me sale error y no he podido dar con la solución. El error que me sale es Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')

Espero que me haga hecho entender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de consultar varios foros, pude encontrar la solución. Lo coloco para aquellos que puedan estar presentando la misma falla. Para recordar la falla, era que no me dejaba agregar columnas al dataTable de acuerdo al tipo de usuario:

```js
var grupo = columnasCondicionales = [], columnasNuevas = [];
if (tipoUser == 1 || tipoUser == 2) {
    columnasCondicionales.push({"data": null, "orderable": false});
    columnasCondicionales.push({"data": null, "orderable": false});
    columnasNuevas.push({
        targets: -5,
        className: 'dt-body-center',
        render: function (data, type, row) {
            return "<button class='btn btn-outline-secondary hint--bottom hint--rounded hint--info botonBloquear' aria-label='" + $('#mBloquear').val() + " No. " + row.ORDEN_PEDIDO_NUMERO + "'><span class='icon-eye1'></span></button>";
        }
  });
    columnasNuevas.push({
        targets: -4,
        className: 'dt-body-center',
        render: function (data, type, row) {
            return "<button class='btn btn-outline-secondary botonConfirmar hint--bottom hint--info hint--rounded' aria-label='" + $('#mConfirmar').val() + "'><span class='icon-lock'></span></button>";
        }
    });
} else if (grupo == 11) {
    columnasCondicionales.push({"data": null, "orderable": false});
    columnasNuevas.push({
        targets: -5,
        className: 'dt-body-center',
        render: function (data, type, row) {
            return "<button class='btn btn-outline-secondary botonBloquear hint--bottom hint--info hint--rounded' aria-label='" + $('#mBloquear').val() + " No. " + row.ORDEN_PEDIDO_NUMERO + "'><span class='icon-eye1'></span></button>";
        }
   });
} else if (grupo == 15) {
    columnasCondicionales.push({"data": null, "orderable": false});
    columnasNuevas.push({
        targets: -4,
        className: 'dt-body-center',
        render: function (data, type, row) {
            return "<button class='btn btn-outline-secondary botonConfirmar hint--bottom hint--info hint--rounded' aria-label='" + $('#mConfirmar').val() + "'><span class='icon-lock'></span></button>";
        }
    });
}
var dtTable = $('#tabla1').DataTable({
    "ajax":{
        "url": 'orden_pedido_acciones.php?accion=' + accionv,
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
    "columns":[
        {"data": null, "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
            return meta.row + 1;// La columna 0 ahora contendrá el número consecutivo
        }},
        {
            "data": null,
            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                var orderId = row.ORDEN_PEDIDO_ID; // ID de la OP
                return "<a href='?number=" + orderId + "' class='number_ope hint--left-middle hint--rounded' aria-label='Editar/Detallar OP No. " + row.ORDEN_PEDIDO_NUMERO + "'><strong>" + row.ORDEN_PEDIDO_NUMERO + "</strong></a>";
            }
        },
        {"data": "CLIENTE_NOMBRE"},
        {"data": "CIUDAD_NOMBRE"},
        {"data": "BODEGA_NOMBRE"},
        {"data": "ORDEN_PEDIDO_FECHA_CREACION"},
        {
            "data": "REFERENCIA",
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                // Reemplaza las comas con saltos de línea
                return data.replace(/,/g, '<br>');
            }
        },
        {
            "data": "CANT",
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                // Reemplaza las comas con saltos de línea
                return data.replace(/,/g, '<br>');
            }
        },
        {
            "data": "CATEGORIA_NOMBRE",
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
            // Reemplaza las comas con saltos de línea
            return data.replace(/,/g, '<br>');
        }
    },
    {"data": "NOMBRE"},
    {"data": "ORDEN_PEDIDO_ESTADO"},
    ...columnasCondicionales,
    {
        "data": "ORDEN_PEDIDO_DOC_HELISA",
        "render": function (data, type, row) {
            // Verificar si hay un documento adjunto
            if (data && data !== "") {
                // Construir el enlace de descarga
                  var ruta = "Clientes/Canal/Facturas/";
                  var enlace = "<a download href='" + ruta + data + "' class='hint--bottom-left hint--rounded hint--info' aria-label='Descargar factura'>" + data + "</a>";
                  return enlace;
            } else {
                  // Si no hay documento adjunto, no mostrar nada
                  return "";
            }
      }
    },
    {"data": "ORDEN_PEDIDO_DOC_ISUPPORT"},
    {"data": null, "orderable": false}
    ],
    columnDefs: [
        {
            targets: -1, // Índice de la nueva columna (antes de la última)
            className: 'dt-body-center',
            "defaultContent": "<button class='btn btn-outline-secondary botonDescargarPDF hint--left hint--info hint--rounded' aria-label='" + $('#mDescargar').val() + "'><span class='icon-file-pdf-o'></span></button>",
            data: null
        },
        ...columnasNuevas
    ],
    'rowCallback': function (row, data, index){
      var buttonDescargarPDF = $(row).find('td:eq(15) button');// Captura el enlace de descarga de PDF
            buttonDescargarPDF.attr('value', data.ORDEN_PEDIDO_ID); // Asigna el ID de la campaña al enlace de descarga de PDF
    },
    "lengthMenu": [
        [10, 25, 50, -1],
        [10, 25, 50, "Todos"]
    ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.2/js/dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>

<table class="table table-stripped table-bordered table-hover" id="tabla1" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">No. OP</th>
            <th scope="col">Cliente</th>
            <th scope="col">Ciudad</th>
            <th scope="col">Bodega</th>
            <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
            <th scope="col">Referencia</th>
            <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
            <th scope="col">Categoría</th>
            <th scope="col">Vendedor</th>
            <th scope="col">Estado</th>
            <?php 
                $tipoUser = 1;
        $grupo = '';
        if ($tipoUser == 1 || $tipoUser == 2) {
                    echo '<th scope="col">Bloquear</th>';
                    echo '<th scope="col">Confirmar</th>';
                }else if ($grupo == 11){
                    echo '<th scope="col">Bloquear</th>';
                }else if ($grupo == 15){
                    echo '<th scope="col">Confirmar</th>';
                }   
            ?>
            <th scope="col">No. Factura</th>
            <th scope="col">No. Salidad</th>
            <th scope="col">PDF</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

En este código, he creado un array columnasCondicionales que se llena dinámicamente según las condiciones que tengas. Luego, al definir las columnas en la configuración del DataTable, uso el operador spread (...) para incluir las columnas condicionales en la posición que desees.

Comment: No olvides mencionar además cuál fue en realidad el problema. Pulsa en [edit] y agrega más detalles.